# How do I display a <

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, markdown

How do I display the character <
with stuff right after it, on the same line?

If I try to write '<' with 'host' right after it (no space), it shows the space  the same if I use a newline char

Comment: One space in front if it and one thereafter

Comment: Have you tried just using backticks? That sounds like something which should be in a code font anyway....

Answer (score 18):

```
&lt;host
```

becomes

<host

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like this is likely to be part of quoting code anyway, so use backticks.

For example, `foo <host` in a line...

... is created with text of:

```
For example, `foo <host` in a line...
```